# code to transform lat long coordinates to pixel coordinates using 4 known GCP points

Tags: java, python, gdal, qgis

I want to use gdal library to transform coordinates (long/lat to pixel coordinates) using 4 known GCP points. (I have values for them in both systems). I am able to manually do it in QGIS using the GUI but I have a huge dataset, therefore would need some java/python code. I have been looking at the apis for quite sometime, but not able to figure out.

Comment: The mapnik library is very good for plotting beautiful maps.

Comment: What about [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies. I was able to accomplish this using gdal jre. The following link shows how to transform coordinates

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2009-June/021052.html

Although its in C#, it can similarly be used in java using the gdal jre.